# Clases y métodos S3 en R. ¿Cuál es su utilidad?

Tags: r, poo, funciones, programación-funcional

Estoy leyendo el texto "Advanced R" de Hadley Wickham y, entrando a la sección de "Crear nuevos métodos y genéricos" para S3, la explicación queda, a mi gusto, bastante en el aire.

Señala Wickham que, para crear una nueva función genérica, debemos crear una función que invoque UseMethod(), algo así como:

```
add <- function(x) UseMethod()
```

Sin embargo, una genérica no es útil sin algunos métodos y para añadir uno, creamos una función regular con el formato correcto (generic.class):

```
add.v <- function(x) "Class v"
v <- structure(vector(), class="v")
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿qué implicaciones tiene esto para una función como la que se desarrolla aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959933/how-to-improve-a-seeker-for-databases-in-r-see-code/48985519# o incluso para funciones tan simples como?:

```
add1 <- function(x) {
return(x+1)
}
```

Agradezco cualquier orientación al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, unos comentarios previos: Para el que viene de otros lenguajes, digase `Python`, `C++` o `Java`, puede que la forma en que se implementa **OOP** en **R** llame un poco la atención. De hecho, puede resultar extraño que haya más de un, llamemosle protocolo, para implementar técnicas de **OOP**. El **S3** de tu consulta, es históricamente la primer implementación de **OOP** en el lenguaje, está y **S4** son las mas comunes, sin embargo hay otras como R5/R6/otras ([ver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9522858/6836377)). El otro comentario es que cuando hablamos de funciones genéricas, estamos hablando de polimorfismo de funciones. En el caso particular  de tu pregunta, estamos viendo como "anexar" una funcionalidad a múltiples clases de objetos ya definidos.

Lo siguiente a comentar, es que la técnica aplica tanto a funciones clásicas como a las funciones de notación `infix` o `binarias`, ejemplo de estas últimas, las operaciones aritméticas (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`), el producto escalar `%*%` y tantísimas otras). Cómo tu ejemplo es una función de este último tipo, vamos a ver un caso similar.

Supongamos que queremos hacer una función para incrementar un objeto, un determinado porcentaje.

Por ejemplo, podríamos definir esto:

```
'%+p%' <- function(x, porcentaje) {
    x + (x * porcentaje/100 )
}
```

El llamado es sencillo y bastante claro:

```
v <- c(2,5,1)
v %+p% 10
[1] 2.2 5.5 1.1
```

Esto funciona incluso con un `data.farme` con solo datos numéricos:

```
df <- data.frame(v=v)
df %+p% 10
    v
1 2.2
2 5.5
3 1.1
```

Ahora que pasa, si por ejemplo, quiseramos usarlo con un `data.frame`más complejo:

```
 df <- data.frame(perido=c("enero", "febrero", "marzo"), consumo=c(100, 450, 600))
df %+p% 10
  perido consumo
1     NA     110
2     NA     495
3     NA     660
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
```

¿Que es esto!!? nada del otro mundo, el problema de una función cuya entrada no contempla este tipo de `dataframe`. En este caso, R intentó ejecutar `x + (x * porcentaje/100 )`, con las columnas numéricas no hubo problemas, pero con la de los caracteres, obviamente no funcionó, resultando en valores `NA` y unos warnings indeseados. Una posibilidad es que nuestra función verifique el tipo de objeto de entrada y actué en consecuencia, la otra es crear una función polimórfica, que es lo que verdaderamente nos interesa en este momento. La idea es crear una función `%+p%` que funcione con un vector de números como con un objeto más complejo como un `data.frame` con columnas de distintos tipos.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es indicarle a R que `%+p%` va a ser una función genérica (polimórfica), para esto es que se usa `UseMethod`, de la siguiente forma:

```
'%+p%' <- function(x, ...) {
    UseMethod('%+p%',x)
}
```

Esto obviamente no implementa ninguna funcionalidad especial, solo le indica al interprete que cuando deba ejecutar `%+p%` en realidad vaya en primer lugar a buscar `%+p%.<clase>`, por ejemplo `%+p%.data.frame`, `%+p%.numeric`, etc. Una función especial es `%+p%.default`, esta es la que se ejecutará en caso que el objeto no tenga definido ninguna función particular. La clase de un objeto la averiguamos usando `class(objeto)`. Ahora sí  a implementar todo:

```
'%+p%.default' <- function(x, porcentaje) {
    x + (x * porcentaje/100 )
}

'%+p%.data.frame' <- function(x, porcentaje) {
    cols <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
    x[, cols] <- x[, cols] + (x[, cols] * porcentaje/100)
    return(x)
}
```

Implementamos un `%+p%.default` que lo que hace es simplemente sumar un determinado porcentaje al objeto y luego un `%+p%.data.frame` para que aplique solo a los `data.frame`, la lógica es sencilla, solo incrementaremos el porcentaje en columnas numéricas, el resto lo dejamos como esta. Y si probamos todo esto:

```
v <- c(2,5,1)
df <- data.frame(perido=c("enero", "febrero", "marzo"), consumo=c(100, 450, 600))

v %+p% 10
[1] 2.2 5.5 1.1

df %+p% 10
   perido consumo
1   enero     110
2 febrero     495
3   marzo     660
```

Y ahora, como por arte de magia, la función `%+p%` funciona perfectamente bien en los dos casos del ejemplo.

#### ¿Pero... y la pregunta?

Bien, a lo que queríamos llegar es:

> ¿qué implicaciones tiene esto para una función como la que se
>   desarrolla aquí
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959933/how-to-improve-a-seeker-for-databases-in-r-see-code/48985519#
>   o incluso para funciones tan simples como?:
>
> ```
> add1 <- function(x) {
> return(x+1)
> }
> ```

Implicaciones, muchas o ninguna. Lo primero es identificar si una determinada funcionalidad tiene aplicación en múltiples tipos de objetos y si la implementación de dicha funcionalidad necesariamente va a ser distinta en cada caso. En tu ejemplo, la función `%$%` se aplica a un `data.frame`, y no a cualquiera, sino a `mtcars` en particular,  por lo que te diría que el polimorfismo nada tiene que hacer aquí, incluso si quisiéramos reformular la función para que aplique a distintos `data.frame` sería un caso para hacer simplemente que la función sea más genérica pero tampoco de polimorfismo.

Comment: Ahora todo tiene sentido, Muchas gracias. ¿Tienes alguna referencia en español para clases y métodos en R ya sea tuya o ajena? Saludos,

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, la verdad nada para recomendarte, lamentablemente R tiene poco material en español en general, muy pocos libros de editoriales que se puedan conseguir y por lo que ví, bastante generales y básicos. Hay bastante material de universidades pero suele estar muy orientado a la estadística dura. OOP es algo que tal vez interese más a los programadores que a los estadísticos en sí, por lo que no ví nada interesante, salvo obviamente notas y blogs. En inglés si hay bastante más material, el libro que estás leyendo obviamente es uno de ellos.

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces seguiré preguntando por aquí esperando continuar recibiendo retroalimentación de personas como tú. Saludos.

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿ '%+p%.default' define la forma general de la función y '%+p%.data.frame' la forma específica en que operará en objetos tipo data.frame?

Comment: Exactamente, igualmente es posible no haber definido una forma general, y tener solo formas particulares de cada clase.